# Change multiple attributes along with text of <a> tag in jQuery using attr() method

Tags: jquery

Here is the element that I want to manipulate :

`<a href="https://www.google.com" id='link_one'>This is Google!</a>`

Here is the jQuery code to change the `href` and `text` properties of that element :

```
$('#link_one').attr({
    href: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
    text: 'This is StackOverflow!'
});
```

The above jQuery code only changes the `href` property but not the `text` property. The following however works:

```
$('#link_one').text('This is StackOverflow!');
```

What I have tried :

```
$('#link_one').attr({
    href: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
    "text": 'This is StackOverflow!'
});

$('#link_one').attr({
    href: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
    "textContent": 'This is StackOverflow!'
});

$('#link_one').attr({
    href: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
    "innerHTML": 'This is StackOverflow!'
});
```

I have even tried the above approaches without putting the property name in quotes. What do I put into the attr() parameter to achieve the required state?

Comment: text is a function not a property of `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the text **(This is Google!)** inside of the  tag is not an attribute of the  tag. It's just an element of the  tag. That's why you can't change that text using attr() method. You have to change it by using text() or html() method. But you can change the href as it is an attribute of the  tag

```js
$('#link_one').attr({
    href: 'https://stackoverflow.com'
}).text("That is stackoverflow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id='link_one'>This is Google!</a>
```

.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way to change the text of <a> using the attr() method since text is not an attribute of <a>. Got it!

Comment: Yes, you can change all other attributes of <a> like target, type, href, id, class etc. Have a look at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) . Happy to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Text is not an attribute of `<a>` elements. You have to assign the text using jquery's `.text` function.

```js
$('#link_one').attr({
    href: 'https://stackoverflow.com'
}).text('This is StackOverflow!');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="link_one" href="">Initial text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor have not attribute text. You try to change text / html not attribute so why it's not working. Try this way:

```js
$('#link_one').attr({
  href: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
  placeholder: 'This is StackOverflow!'
}).html('This is StackOverflow!');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id='link_one'>This is Google333!</a>
```